# How to display Android push notification with no title/time on 3 lines

Tags: android, push-notification

I have seen some apps for which push notifications only display the app icon on the left and the message content on the right, with no title nor time. Also the message content takes the entire space and can occupy up to 3 lines.

[image: Valid XHTML]
.

When I don't supply any title nor text, my message still appears below where the title and time should be. It can only occupy one line and ends up showing only the beginning, with some ellipsis at the end.

I already looked at BigView and BigTextStyle, but it doesn't look like it's what I want, as even if I don't supply a title nor time, the notification message doesn't move up. Also I don't want the user to have to expand the notification to see the whole text.

Is there any simple way to achieve what I want? Or do I have to create a custom layout? I'm using Phonegap and have very limited Android knowledge.

Here is the code I'm currently using: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/src/android/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java (see the createNotification method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any *easy* way to do that, like tweaking existing objects. I guess it always requires creating a [CustomNotification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification), which I did: I created a `RemoteViews` to display things exactly the way I wanted.